# Do we really need a headless browser in running with bitbucket pipelines?

Tags: protractor, continuous-integration, e2e-testing

Do we need a headless browser for CI/CD using with bitbucket pipelines?

Although I have used with both the options, with and without headless, and the test ran in both the scenarios.

If its not true then why are we adviced to use a headless browser with CI/CD?

Information: When using without headless browser such as chrome in bitbucket pipelines it does not opens the browser window.

Comment: This question may be more suitable for https://sqa.stackexchange.com